# Compare rows with same identifier in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, compare

I am having a table in a database (SQL Server) which looks like this

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| id | p_id         | dummyColumn2 | l_id     |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 8            | someData1    | 20       |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 2  | 13           | someData2    | 20       |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 3  | 8            | someData1    | 21       |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 4  | 13           | someData2_c  | 21       |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Where I want to compare if rows with same p_id but with different l_id are same or not and if not same , get the p_id. (in this case query should return 13, as it's different from second record with p_id = 13 )

**Some additional information:**
Imagine p_id represents the Unique Identifier and l_id represents which record is latest inserted , so I am comparing old rows
(with l_id = 20) with new rows (with l_id = 21) and getting if it has changed or not.

*Also please note this table is simplified , so in real case scenario it has much more columns and rows*

Would appreciate any help and would like to know if this problem can be solved using Joins.

-- There is a Query I came up to but it doesn't seems to works

```
//Getting latest l_id 
declare @a int 
set @a = (Select top(1) l_id from thisTable order by l_id desc) 

SELECT NEW.p_id
FROM   thisTable AS OLD
       INNER JOIN thisTable AS NEW
         ON OLD.p_id = NEW.p_id
WHERE  OLD.l_id = @a-1
       AND NEW.l_id = @a
AND OLD.dummyColumn2 <> NEW.dummyColumn2 
AND ... (same for other columns)
```

**EDIT:**
Imagine there are 1000 rows and 200 of them has l_id 18 , then another 200 has l_id 19 and so on . I am comparing rows with highest l_id to the one which was before that (like l_id = 21 and l_id = 20)
higher l_id means that data is newer than data with lower l_ids

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i got the question :)

```
Select * from
thistable as A
join thistable as B on A.P_ID=B.P_ID
where A.l_id<>B.l_ID and A.dummycolumn2<>B.dummycolumn2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this via `exists`:

```
select *
from t as t1
where exists (
    select *
    from t as t2
    where t2.p_id = t1.p_id -- t2 is same group
    and   t2.l_id < t1.l_id -- t2 is an older row
    and   t2.dummyColumn2 <> t1.dummyColumn2 -- status (?) is different
)
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seems to work . I have tested it and manually changed values for rows to be different and it always shows empty table as a result

Comment: The logic is in accordance with how you described in _some additional information_. It does ignore nulls.